# How to use Django custom template tags to get an attribute of an object?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've written a custom tag and it is working. No problem there.
However, while the template tag returns the model object that I need, I'm not able to go one step further and get an attribute of that object. As shown below:

models.py

```
class ExamScore(models.Model):
    exam_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    reading = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    uofe = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,
                           verbose_name='use of English')
    writing = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    listening = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    speaking = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

custom_tags.py

```
@register.simple_tag
def unique_exam(student_id, exam_name, skill):
    if ExamScore.objects.filter(student_id=student_id, exam_name=exam_name).exists():
        e = ExamScore.objects.get(student_id=student_id, exam_name=exam_name).skill
        return e
    else:
        return ''
```

template.html

```
<input type="number"
       step="0.01" 
       class="score" 
       id="score-re" 
       value="{% unique_exam student.id exam_name 'reading' %}"
       placeholder="36">
 #  the trouble is here where it says 'reading'
 #  I have also tried 'reading' with double quotes and no quotes
```

'reading' is the attribute I want in this case, at other times it is speaking, listening, etc. Which is why I can't hard code it, and have to pass it through the tag as an argument.

What I get is this:

## AttributeError at /teacher/exams/PreCourse/

### 'ExamScore' object has no attribute 'skill'

The traceback specifically tells me the issue is at:

line 17.           e = ExamScore.objects.get(student_id=student_id, exam_name=exam_name).skill

I know there is no attribute 'skill', it is a variable which should hold the name of the ExamScore object attribute.
Local vars says it does:

> ```
> ▼ Local vars
> ```
>
> Variable:  Value
>
> exam_name:     'PreCourse'
>
> skill:     'reading'
>
> student_id:     4

SO, my question is how can I assign a skill type (e.g. reading, listening...) to a variable and append that to my ExamScore object to get that attribute to put in my form as a value?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in, which is intended when trying to fetch an attribute dinamically (emphasis mine):

> **Return the value of the named attribute of object**. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise **AttributeError** is raised.

In your custom tag, you should try:

```
@register.simple_tag
def unique_exam(student_id, exam_name, skill):
    if ExamScore.objects.filter(student_id=student_id, exam_name=exam_name).exists():
        e = ExamScore.objects.get(student_id=student_id, exam_name=exam_name)
        e = getattr(e, skill, "")
        return e
    else:
        return ''
```

Comment: I edited my answer to prevent storing ``"None"`` in your ``value`` JS variable

Answer (score 0):

It's because no attribute `skill` is in your `ExamScore` model. So when retrieved tha `ExamScore` object in your template tag, it tries to access to `skill` attribute which doesn't exist on your table.

Comment: In my question I wrote: "I know there is no attribute 'skill', it is a variable which should hold the name of the ExamScore object attribute."